# JS File Loading Selectively

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, contextmenu

I am working with [contextMenu.js](http://ignitersworld.com/lab/contextMenu.html), and it was mostly working fine. Technically, it's still working fine when the page has a low load of things to do, but when there is also a form loaded on the page there runs a risk of this error:

```
TypeError: $(...).contextMenu is not a function
```

It's not that it simply hasn't loaded yet. I can wait a long time and try to add the context menu and I still get the error. It seemingly happens at random, although certain pages are more prone than others I can load the page 10 times and get the error nine of the times. Other pages I'll get the error one out of ten times. Essentially, on occasion it doesn't see the contextMenu function and other times it does.

I've already played around with the load order, and jquery is the first thing to load and I can still use jquery throughout the rest of the document, so I don't think it's a problem with jquery. I'm at a loss, any ideas?

Here's my code:

```
function createSavedReportsMenu(name, location, report, fileNumber){
// creates the popup menu for the saved reports area

var menu = [{  //begin first item on the pop up menu
    name: 'Run Report', // the name that is displayed for the first button
    img: '/Reports/images/run.png', // display an image
    title: 'run button', // mouse over text
    fun: function () {
       //do something
    }
}, {
    name: 'Load Parameters',
    img: '/Reports/images/load.png',
    title: 'load button',
    fun: function () {
        //do something
    }
}, {
    name: 'Rename Report',
    img: '/Reports/images/rename.png',
    title: 'rename button',
    fun: function () {
        //do something
    }
}, {
    name: 'Delete',
    img: '/Reports/images/delete.png',
    title: 'delete button',
    fun: function () {
          //do something
    }
}];
var reportDiv = "#file" + fileNumber;
try{
$(reportDiv).contextMenu(menu);
}catch(err){
    alert(err);
}
```

}

Comment: How are you using the function? Is it with `$(document).ready()` or `$(window).load()`?

Comment: i bet you are loading more than 1 copy of jQuery, and that the 2nd one wipes out all your plugins. some scripts like to load their own copy of jQuery, and that can be problematic, especially if they load an older one.

Comment: @ntgCleaner No, the contextMenu's are being added to list items that are dynamically generated, so I can't run the code when the document or window is loaded, it has to be done after I fetch the file list and display the data.

Comment: @dandavis If that was problem, wouldn't it fail every time rather than only some of the time? Also, it doesn't seem to include it's own JS file, and all the other plugins are working.

Comment: some scripts will just ask if(!window.jQuery) before loading, so if jq wasn't loaded at that point (but was dispatched), then it can happen. it depends on bundling, defer/async attribs, script loaders, remote timeouts, and a whole lot of other edge-cases. i'm just suggesting one thing that could cause the symptoms you describe; jQuery loaded but plugin not but plugin still visible in devtools network tab

Comment: @dandavis Do you have any suggestions on how to get around it?

Comment: on the times the error happens, can you see the function by running $("body").contentMenu in the console after the page has loaded, or is that undefined? a link to an example would help us fashion a fix.

Comment: @dandavis I added the code to my post. I can't type $("body").contextMenu in the console because I would need to pass in a menu object. I tried doing that and I got SyntaxError: missing ; before statement.

Comment: no, you don't need to run the plugin, just see if it's there...

Comment: @dandavis When I type $("body").contextMenu in the console of firefox I get SyntaxError: missing ; before statement

Comment: @dandavis I should also mention that I tried reloading contextMenu.js dynamically, and still no dice.